# Seeking suggestions for data display for table with supercategories, sections and bold-heatmap? dartboard?

Tags: data-visualization, reporting, heatmap

I'm trying to visually display the results of a table where we used vote counting to categorically summarize (in many ways) multiple outcomes from a list of studies and compare to how they were reported in systematic reviews as a way to describe possible selective outcome reporting. Here's a picture of the table and caption:

[image: The table captures the 1 continuous variable-the number of outcomes reported in a study, and summarizes that by categorical variables: the overall vote count of cross-sectional, longitudinal, bivariate and multivariate outcomes and how outcomes were reported in each review. It is arranged into supercategories of studies: Ones that actually did measure specific associations between the chosen exposure and outcomes, ones that measured the association but these associations were not reported in any review, and ones that did not measure an association by our definition of exposure and outcome (example: saying an outcome was for depression but measuring it with an overall depression/anxiety scale score) yet were reported in a review anyway.]

It has been suggested that we present this visually. The person suggesting it pointed us to a heatmap (their example shows reviews along the x axis, arranged chronologically by publication date, and specific outcomes as rectangles (e.g., treatment A, treatment B) along the y axis with color of the rectangle indicating whether each study included it or not.

Can anyone suggest ways to capture all of this in one or more plots or displays? Here's another way I've been thinking of it, roughly listed by general to specific findings given our research question and study goals (is there selective outcome reporting in the reviews):

1. What did each review report as the outcome? (*currently column under
   supercategory*)
2. Was the outcome even reported in the reviews that
   contained it (*currently section of the table*)
3. Did the study actually measure the association between exposure and outcome as we defined it? (*currently section of the table*)
4. Was there robustness for the vote counting results? (*currently* *bold font in the table*)
5. What were the overall vote counting results for cross-sectional, longitudinal, bivariate and multivariate analyses (*currently columns*)
6. How many outcomes did each study have overall? (*currently first column*)

I've seen some brilliant ways to display findings of selective outcomes reporting, but I'm not actually a "methods person", so I'm hoping someone whose good at this will give me some suggestions for displaying all this info, maybe in a heatmap, dartboard, or similar. Here are some papers with cool displays from people who specialize in systematic reviews/meta-analysis:

https://academic.oup.com/ije/article/46/6/1999/4061562

https://www.jclinepi.com/article/S0895-4356(17)30721-7/abstract

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!